# Sublime Text 2 Sass Closing Brace

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

I'm using SublimeSaveOnBuild. When my scss files compiles to css, the resulting code displays the closing brace like this:

```
.content {
    padding-left: 10px; }
```

I'd like it to generate the closing brace in the traditional format:

```
.content {
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this automatically so it compiles each selector with the closing brace on its own line?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the *compiled* CSS to look a certain way?

Comment: I'd like it to stay consistent with the rest of my team's projects, which are not always using Sass.

Answer (score 3):

There's a Sass setting called `style` that controls the look of the output. The default is `nested`, which is what you're seeing: Just switch it to `expanded` and you'll get the more traditional look you want.

See [the documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style) to find the right way to change it for your setup.

Here's an example from the documentation that shows how it will look:

```
// nested
#main {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000; }
  #main p {
    width: 10em; }

// expanded
#main {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
#main p {
  width: 10em;
}
```

Comment: Not for me. I still get the closing bracket along the last line, instead of on its own line.

Comment: Are you sure the style flag is being picked up? I'd try changing it to `compressed`, just to check, and if the output is still the same then the problem is likely with the setup.

Comment: It seems like there's nothing wrong with my setup, as I get clear difference between `nested` and `expanded`. It's just that the closing bracket in `expanded` does not get it own line.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know then; seems like the behavior does not match the documentation. I didn't see any other options that would control this output.

Comment: This worked for me `sass custom.scss custom.css --style expanded`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grunt, adding options like this might help (using grunt-contrib-sass):

```
sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
            style: 'expanded'
        }, 
        files: {
            'style.css' : 'sass/style.scss'
        }
      }
    }
```